# How can Customer community user login into Salesforce using REST API?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, integration, apexrest

I have created one Rest webservice in SFDC (which I want to expose to other users) and set up one CUSTOMER community User.

Login URL:

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password
```

I am trying to retrieve access_token using postman but getting the response:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

params which i send with request are :

```
client_id,client_secret,username,password,grant_type="password", response_type="code",content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

where username is community user`s username and his password.

How we can retrieve session id for community user using REST API ?

Comment: The customer community profile does not support API access so that might be blocking this.

Comment: I found the solution, check out [Customer Community User login using Partner WSDL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245808/customer-community-user-login-using-partner-wsdl?noredirect=1#comment373907_245808)