# Customer Community User login using Partner WSDL

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, customer-community, login, partner-wsdl

**Requirement** :- Login Customer community user into Salesforce using Partner WSDL.

I tried solution provided [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111687/customer-community-login-using-rest-api/245790) and it works for customer community users for me using SOAP UI.

But when I used partner wsdl and the c# code shared in [Salesforce examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm) for customer community users, I am getting error : ***An unexpected error has occurred: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.***

The same code is working for Salesforce User license users, I am able to get session id for Salesforce user License successfully.

Is there any API login issue for customer community license?

Comment: Can you try this?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/201012/19118

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well, Profile level- API enabled and pass credentials using soap ui got the successful response. but when I used partner wsdl and the c# code shared in Salesforce examples[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm] for customer community users, I am getting error : **An unexpected error has occurred: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.,**

Comment: Is thre IP based login restiction for your community profile user?

Comment: No IP based restrictions for customer community profile. 
Login IP range for customer community profile is 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.

Comment: Are you passing the Org Id in your C# code? Checkout the example here [LoginScopeHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm)

Comment: Thank you Aayush for reply, it works for me. Able to login in sfdc using Partner.WSDL for customer community users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the below solution which works for me.

**Solution:**

1. Clone customer community profile with restricted access (enabled API access)
2. Create a new Customer community user with a new profile.
3. Generate Partner WSDL and shared in C# project with org Id. (for C# project I have used Visual Studio 2013 tool)
4. In C# code, Call Login Method in Partner.WSDL with customer community credentials and SFDC Organization Id.
5. Retrieve session id and call customize REST/SOAP webservice or we can call query using query() function.

***My C# code:***

```
public bool login(){
// Web Reference to the imported Partner WSDL.
SforceService partnerBinding = new SforceService();

// To authenticate Self-Service users, we need to set the OrganizationId
// in the LoginScopeHeader.
string orgId = "Your Org Id";
partnerBinding.LoginScopeHeaderValue = new LoginScopeHeader();
partnerBinding.LoginScopeHeaderValue.organizationId = orgId;

String uname = "Customer Community Username";
String pwd = "Customer Community Password";
try
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    Console.WriteLine("\nLogging in...\n");
    LoginResult lr1 = partnerBinding.login(uname, pwd);
    // Set the returned service endpoint URL
    partnerBinding.Url = lr1.serverUrl;
    // Set the SOAP header with the session ID returned by
    // the login result. This will be included in all
    // API calls.
    partnerBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
    partnerBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr1.sessionId;
    Console.WriteLine("lr1.sessionId:- " + lr1.sessionId);
}
catch (SoapException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

// Return true to indicate that we are logged in, pointed  
// at the right URL and have our security token in place.     
return true;
```

}

Copy and paste above code and run C# application and you will receive sessionid related to customer community user.

C# Code references: [LoginScopeHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm)